# Why the android awesomeplayer was made using struct not class

Tags: android

I found that the native layer of android uses class and struct.

For example, `MediaPlayer`, `Stagefrightplayer`, `Audioplayer`, `MetaData` was class.
But `Awesomeplayer` and `MediaSource` are struct.

Although I read that class and struct is similar in use, I wonder why `Awesomeplayer` was created as struct. Is there any reason or just developer's taste?

Answer (score 1):

[image]You try to mention `awesomeplayer`  and `MediaSource` as Android APIs? No, they aren't, they are converted structures from C++; they do not belong to Android libraries!

please see the diagram of `stagefright`, the lib is from C/C++ core. Android is linux core, and can bring the C/C++ utils, libs into it.

Reference: http://pierrchen.blogspot.sg/2012/03/share-with-you-what-have-learned-about.html

Comment: What does it mean "converted structures from C++"?
AwesomePlayer.cpp is built into the libstagefright.so.
And Awawesomeplayer's instance is created at the StagefrightPlayer.

Comment: I could not find the relation between your answer and my question.
My question is why the AwesomePlayer is declared as struct not as class.
I wonder this fact has effect on system or is just developer's taste.

Comment: So I am wondering that you CAN "understand" the STRUCT in Java. Are you C/C++ programmer or Java one? Just show me how to declare a struct in Java? Are you kidding me? :D

Comment: Now, I think you wrongly posted your question in this forum; it's not appropriate here. The better way is you add tag of C, C++ to your question. But I guarantee that it will be ignored, though I am also fluent in C/C++ but would give no answer here.

Comment: Dear Kelvin.
I hope you are not angry about my question and descripton.
I am grateful for your answer. I think you did misunderstand my words.
I thought that AwesomePlayer is android's component and this question could be appropriate with Android tag. And in that point ov view, I asked why did they make AwesomePlayer as struct.
So, I needed the answer of android engineer who experienced Stagefirght and AwesomePlayer.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I am not angry, nvr mind. As C/C++ developer point of view, Struct is for objects with default public access to its members. So for `AwesomePlayer` which should be wrapped in Java for Android developer, things migrated from C lib so should be provided with access to its utils.